# Add library built by ant source code to my eclipse project java?

Tags: java, ant, openstreetmap

i want to integrate a project built by ant in to my eclipse java project . i am using JMapView library.i want to integrate it in to my project.

Comment: Is it built as a jar file?

Comment: no.. just src and build.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try create new project from existing Ant build file. Then add this project  to build path of your project.